# How to replace letters at specific positions in swift

Tags: ios, swift

First time coder here. Am on process of making hangman app from scratch without tutorials as part of challenge in HWS.

I created UI with UIkit and made a custom keyboard by using UIButtons()

My scenario is

Let the word be SWIFT

- if the word has 5 characters it will be displayed as xxxxx (5 times x)
- when I select W UIButton the xxxxx changes into xWxxx
- if there letter is repeated more than one times. Like LETTER, if I press T, xxxxxx changes to xxTTxx.

But I don’t know how to change letter at specific index locations.

Here’s how my code kinda looks like.

```
@objc func buttonTapped (_ sender: UIButton) {
Guard let buttonTitle = sender.titleLabel?..text else { return} 

If answer.contains(buttonTitle) { //button title is single letter string I get from buttons qwerty...

var answerLabelTemp = answerLabel.text //text is xxxxx answer is correct answer 

let letterPos = answer.firstIndex(of: buttonTitle.first!)

answerLabelTemp = answerLabelTemp!.replacingOccurrences(of: “x”, with: buttonTitle.first!) // getting error here

answerLabel.text = answerLabelTemp 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to replacing characters in strings is to turn the word into an array of `String` and replace the letters directly.  Use `.joined()` to turn that array back into a `String`:

```
// the hidden word is elephant
let word = "elephant"
let wordArray = word.map(String.init)
print(wordArray)
```

> ["e", "l", "e", "p", "h", "a", "n", "t"]

```
var hidden = Array(repeating: "x", count: word.count)
print(hidden)
```

> ["x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x"]

```
let guessedLetter = "e"

// now fill in a guessed letter
for index in hidden.indices {
    if wordArray[index] == guessedLetter {
        hidden[index] = guessedLetter
    }
}

// turn array back into a String with joined()
print(hidden.joined())
```

> exexxxxx